# Container row alignment issue

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on my first ever website, this is using the twitter-bootstrap 4 framework. Everything was going swimmingly, until I have seemingly encountered the following issue.

I currently have this layout for my website:

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXUBr.jpg)

When in fact I would like:

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHcMs.jpg)

I have attempted a plethora of solutions that I have found via browsing stack-overflow, such as nesting columns. None of it seems to work, I'm sure it is simply due to my inexperience, but I'm stumped as to how to get my desired appearance.

```
    <div class="container-fluid bg-style-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 par-style"><h2 class="par-heading">Welcome to my Website</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide pull-right" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src="img/Christina.JPG" alt="..."></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><img src="img/NickyAndChristina.JPG" alt="..."></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><img src="img/Nicky.JPG" alt="..."></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><img src="img/Meme.JPG" alt="..."></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Christina.JPG" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/NickyAndChristina.JPG" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Nicky.JPG" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Meme.JPG" alt="Fourth slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of Carousel -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-style-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 par-style"><h2 class="par-heading">Test Header</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As seen above, I am trying to have a photo gallery slider to the right of my website and the formatting I have attached above, it simply will not work. Can someone please give me some guidance? I have been thoroughly enjoying working on this website, but I cannot progress until I have resolved this as it will plague my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nedge

https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhanand/4f0pztcu/2/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row container-0">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="row container-1">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
               <img class="rgt-side-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row container-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <img class="rgt-side-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <img class="rgt-side-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <img class="rgt-side-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope this one helps. You can replace img tag with your own contents.

Comment: You are an absolute star, thank you very much. Really helped me to get to grips with the use of containers.